# Accessing specific element from two dimensional character array

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I'm working on a method that takes as input a two dimensional array, a character and 2 integers giving the location of the character in the array. I have to throw an exception whenever the array is full at the location i'm trying to access, or whenever i'm trying to access a location that is out of bounds. Java is giving me a weird error in relation to how I have written my code. I am not sure how to access a certain element from a two dimensional array. I have attached a screenshot of my code and the exception I get. 
Thank you in advance! [Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQ5PY.png)

Comment: Don't post text/code as image/link ([more info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)). Use [edit] option to correct your post.

Comment: Anyway what you expect to happen when you call `borad.charAt[x][y]`? Why not just `board[x][y]` like you wrote few lines after it?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't try to run code that doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

It may be preferable to copy and paste the code and the Exception straight to the question body with `monospace formatting` for easier readability.

The `charAt` function is expected to be called on a `String` object. A `char[][]` array is not a String object, so the code won't compile successfully. Depending on your familiarity with Java you may want to read up on the difference between a class object (such as an instance of the `String` class) and an array of primitive types (such as `char`).

Tutorial page explaining arrays: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Tutorial page explaining classes:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

If you're trying to access a `char` from a two-dimensional `char[][]` array, just think of it like accessing an array of arrays. `char[x]` will get you the "row" containing the element you want and `char[x][y]` will get you the specific element in that "row" of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Since your array is a char array you do not need to put `board.charAt[x][y]` just `board[x][y]`. Also the `finally` bit is always executed so if you put illegal values for `x` or `y` you will still get an error. Furthermore you are not writing the character referenced by the variable `c` to the array, you are writing the character (letter) c into the board. 
You can use the second `if` statement with an `else` to put the character in the array and avoid the `finally` altogether.

```
if(board[x][y] != ' ') throw new IllegalArgumentException("Your message");
else board[x][y] = c;
```

which should go inside the first `if` that you've gotten. 
Another approach is to use `catch` after the `try` because trying to access an element outside of the array will throw an `Exception` anyway.